# Why does my regular expression ALWAYS fail in Go?

Tags: regex, go

I know there are plenty of questions on here asking why their regex fails, but I can't see any specifically for Go/Golang.

I have an ID type which is a string with some methods tacked on: `type ID string`, and this function which is supposed to return a bool if the ID is valid.

My criteria for validity are:

- 20 characters long.
- Any upper case letter A-Z.
- Any digit 0-9.

So my regular expression, which I've tested on a few different online tools is `/[A-Z0-9]{20}/`

But every time I run my validate function it returns false, regardless of input. Specifically, the `regexp.MatchString()` function is returning false and nil.

Below is my validation function, match is ALWAYS false, even when I change the regex to `/.{20}/` which is supposed to match 20 of anything.

```
func (this ID) validate() bool {

    regexString := "/[A-Z0-9]{" + strconv.Itoa(MAX_ID_LENGTH) + "}/"
    fmt.Println(regexString)

    thisStr := this.ToString()
    fmt.Println(thisStr)
    charCount := utf8.RuneCountInString(thisStr)
    fmt.Println(charCount)
    thisStr = strings.ToUpper(thisStr)
    fmt.Println(thisStr)
    match, err := regexp.MatchString(regexString, thisStr)
    fmt.Println(match, err)

    //Check string length is correct and matches regex.
    if charCount != MAX_ID_LENGTH || !match {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Is it to do with the way I'm using the function? I'm stumped.

**Note:** the .ToUpper() function is there because when my IDs are generated they are only produced with upper case letters and 0-9, but I want "abc" to be treated as "ABC" if typed manually at a later date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go regular expressions should not be surrounded with `/` characters. Remove those and see if that works.

The `/` characters are used in some languages (such as javascript and ruby) when creating [regular expression literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) because the `\` character is used frequently in regex and requires double escaping when in a regular string. It's just a convenience in some languages, but typically is not part of the actual regex syntax (though every language handles regex a bit differently).

The Go language does not support regex literals, but it does have the concept of [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals), which makes it much easier to write complex regular expressions.

So, for example, to find the string `\.hidden-file-009`, you could write the expression as:

```
"\\\\\\.[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]*"
```

or, more simply:

```
 `\\\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*`
```

Comment: I had to wait for the 'you can accept this in x minutes message', otherwise I would have straight away.